# What are best methods for solving Biharmonic Equation Analytically

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve deflection of a Kirchoff plate with varying flexural rigidity D and subjected to a uniform load q.
Governing equation is a fourth order nonlinear non-homogeneous partial differential equation. 
I want to solve this equation analytically but I couldn't find out which method I should use (Homotopy perturbation method, Adomian decomp etc.)
For simplicity, if one takes q and D as constants. Equation reduces to 
$$\nabla^4w(x,y) = \frac{q}{D}$$ which is still a hard problem. 
Is there a method to solve both equations analytically.

Comment: You're in luck, the biharmonic equation has a simple [fundamental solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_solution#Biharmonic_equation) in $2$D if you haven't tried that already. Modifying it for the boundary conditions on your plate to get a more specific Green's function may be tricky, though.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thank you for your reply. How can I found a solution for a plate if D=D(x,y).

Comment: Nothing changes. That's how fundamental solutions work.